# Export with default_content

Tags: 8, commerce

I have been able to export the commerce_store, commerce_product_variation and commerce_product entities with the default_content module and the drush dce (default-content-export) command, but when importing back, the products and the product variations are not linked together. What am I missing?

Has anybody managed to export products and import as default content in a drupal commerce 2.0 site?

Answer (score 0):

Commerce currently does not work correctly with default_content. The commerce guys are looking into solutions for delivering default content.

AFAIK the next version of yaml_content is gonna be able to play nicely with commerce. However as of now, the module has no commands for exporting content, only for importing.

[default_content - Question about architecture](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content/issues/2896971)

[yaml_content - Content Export Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/yaml_content/issues/2898704)